# How did they end up on the bus?

Tags: plot-explanation, heist-2015

In the 2015 thriller [*Heist*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heist_(2015_film)) (actually distributed in Australia by the original title of *Bus 657*), how did the criminal ensure that they caught the bus? (Spoilers follow)

> The guy planning the robbery (Cox) had arranged a car in which to escape, but that driver panicked and fled when he heard gunshots. The remaining three hijacked a bus - but one of the other robbers (Vaughn) was setting them up so he could steal all the money.  His plan to double cross them *relied on* being on that bus!

How could he be so sure that the original escape plan would fail?